# How get url Image from Instagram Stories API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I use the Facebook/Instagram Official API for get the list of the [IG Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories).

Now I have a array of ID but, can I use that for get the url of the Image ?

[image: Facebook Tool]

Comment: I found the url is
http://graph.facebook.com/ID_IG_STORY/insights/reach

Comment: Someone know if is also possible have the profile of the people viewing the story ?

Comment: Have you tried what fields Graph API Explorer has to suggest?

Comment: _“possible have the profile of the people viewing the story ?”_ - if you have even ever heard the term _privacy_, that should answer itself, I think.

Comment: 'Have you tried what fields Graph API Explorer has to suggest?' Yes but i don't find anything about the url of the IG Story Image

Comment: @Andrea Merli Did you find a solution?

Comment: @barak109 Nope  sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can send a 'Field' parameter with your request

endpointParams['fields'] = 'id,media_url,permalink,media_type,timestamp' # fields to get back

Answer (score 0):

To get the url of the Video story, call each media-id using thumbnail_url as field, like this:

```
{media-id}/?fields=thumbnail_url
```

But if it is an Image story, the endpoint would be

```
{media-id}/?fields=media_url
```